# How the indexing of a new document wil be done by a couchbase view? Is it being added at last?

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchbase-view

I want to know that if a new document is added to couchbase and I am accessing these kind of documents via a mapreduce view. Then will the new document comse at last in the list of these documents or it can come at nay position in the list?

Answer (score 0):

It does not depends on time of creation but depends totally on your key combinations.

So if you use a `name` field as key, then it will be displayed in alphabetical order.

See [Writing Views](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.0/developer-guide/views-writing.html) for more detail.